# Conditions for elements of numpy arrays with different sizes

Tags: python, numpy, vector, conditional-statements, vectorization

I have the following case in pseudo Python code and need to find a vectorised solution for it for purposes of optimisation, since I'm dealing with hundreds of thousands of entries for speech analysis and nested for loops are unviable. I'm wondering how can I vectorise conditional checks for arrays of different sizes... I am aware of np.greater, for instance, but that is an element wise operation that fails with arrays of different sizes.

```
words = [
    {'id': 0, 'word': 'Stu', 'sampleStart': 882, 'sampleEnd': 40571},
    {'id': 0, 'word': ' ', 'sampleStart': 40570, 'sampleEnd': 44540},
    {'id': 0, 'word': 'eyes', 'sampleStart': 44541, 'sampleEnd': 66590},
]

phonemes = [
    {'id': 0, 'phoneme': ' ', 'sampleStart': 0, 'sampleEnd': 881},
    {'id': 1, 'phoneme': 's', 'sampleStart': 882, 'sampleEnd': 7937},
    {'id': 2, 'phoneme': 't', 'sampleStart': 7938, 'sampleEnd': 11906},
    {'id': 3, 'phoneme': 'u', 'sampleStart': 11907, 'sampleEnd': 15433},
    {'id': 3, 'phoneme': ' ', 'sampleStart': 15434, 'sampleEnd': 47627},
    {'id': 3, 'phoneme': 'eye', 'sampleStart': 47628, 'sampleEnd': 57770},
    {'id': 3, 'phoneme': 's', 'sampleStart': 57771, 'sampleEnd': 66590},
]

associatedData = []
for w in words:
    startWord = w['sampleStart']
    endWord = w['sampleEnd']
    word = w['word']
    w_id = w['id']
    for p in phonemes:
        startPhoneme = p['sampleStart']
        endPhoneme = p['sampleEnd']
        phoneme = p['phoneme']
        p_id = p['id']
        if startPhoneme >= startWord and endPhoneme <= endWord:
            # I need to relate this data as it comes from 2 different sources
            # Some computations occur here that are too ling to reproduce here, this multiplication is just to give an example
            mult = startPhoneme * startWord
            associatedData.append({'w_id' : w_id, 'p_id': p_id, 'word' : word, 'phoneme' : phoneme, 'someOp': startWord})

# Gather associated data for later use:
print(associatedData)
```

What could be a good approach to tackle this issue? I am relatively new to vector operations and I have been struggling with this for quite some hours already without much result.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? It's hard to follow what you're trying to do without seeing what `w` and `p` look like, and without your desired outcome

Comment: It is unclear what exactly do you want to vectorize - I suggest you provide a short example of two things you want to compare and how.

Comment: When arrays differ in size, you usually have to work with them individually.  If they don't fit into one multidimesional array, you can't use the faster whole array methods.

Comment: Excuses, see edited post for a more concrete example

Answer (score 0):

Looking at all possible phonemes for every word will not scale. The amount of work being done is higher than it needs to be. With any number of `words` and `phonemes`, there will always be `len(words) * len(phonemes)` operations with this approach. Vectorization could speed that up, but it's better to instead reduce the complexity itself.

Rather for every word, try to look only at a few phoneme candidates. One solution could be to keep a pointer to the current phoneme around. With every new word, iterate (locally, just around the current phoneme pointer) over the range of matching phonemes.

Pseudo-code solution:

```
# skip if already sorted
words = sorted(words, key=lambda x:x["sampleStart"])
phonemes = sorted(phonemes, key=lambda x:x["sampleStart"])

phoneme_idx = 0
for w in words:

    # go back until the earliest relevant phoneme
    while endtime(phonemes[phoneme_idx]) < starttime(w):
         phoneme_idx -= 1

    # evaluate all phonemes in range
    while endtime(phonemes[phoneme_idx]) <= starttime(w):
         # match and compute
         evavalute(phonemes[phoneme_idx], w)
         phoneme_idx += 1
```